# Cannot get the data from axios with api - vue js

Tags: javascript, laravel, api, vue.js, axios

I have an issue when i get the data with vue js, it returns a HTML not json. I conse the route params it show an id of the post. This is my code in vue:

```
axios.get("api/posts/" + this.$route.params.id).then(response => {
  console.log(this.$route.params.id);
  console.log(response.data);
});
```

And this is the response data :

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>Laravel</title>

        <!-- Fonts -->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,600" rel="stylesheet">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/css/app.css">
        <script src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/js/app.js" defer></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app">
            <index></index>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

But in the postman, i access the url "api/posts/1" it show json data
{"id": 1,"title": "Schambergerstad Fancy Rooms",
"description": "Qui minima tempora ea modi maiores. Quaerat non aut porro vel occaecati. Deleniti quaerat quod veniam. Dolor ducimus facilis molestiae omnis fuga occaecati.",
"created_at": "2020-06-04T11:28:25.000000Z","updated_at": "2020-06-04T11:28:25.000000Z"
    }

But i see in network tab, the request url is "http://127.0.0.1:8000/posts/api/posts/1". Why become to that url? I call it in axios is "api/posts/1"
How to fix it?

Comment: could you show us the request header?

Comment: Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/posts/api/posts/1
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:8000
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

Comment: Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,id;q=0.8
Connection: keep-alive
Host: 127.0.0.1:8000
Referer: http://127.0.0.1:8000/posts/1

Answer (score 2):

try adding headers Content-Type json

```
axios.get("/api/posts/" + this.$route.params.id, {
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
}).then(response => {
  console.log(this.$route.params.id);
  console.log(response.data);
});
```

Comment: I try that, but in url request is "http://127.0.0.1:8000/posts/api/posts/1" not "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/posts/1"

Comment: Then access `axios.get("/api/posts/`

Comment: my bad, i didn't see that as well

Answer (score 0):

Okay sorry it's just typo `axios.get("api/posts/" + this.$route.params.id)` it's should add `"/"` before `"api/posts/"`

```
axios.get("/api/posts/" + this.$route.params.id)
```